# Why radamsa does not generate the requested number of testacases?

Tags: testing, fuzzing, fuzz-testing

I'm trying to do some fuzz testing with radamsa on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The man page says:

> -n,  --count n 
> How many outputs to generate based on the sample(s). Giving -1 or inf causes data to be generated forever. The default is 1.

Anyway if I run a simple example, I obtain this output:

```
$ echo "test" | radamsa -n 100
tgsttfsttest
tes
teBs
teBs
tes
tst
tst
```

As you can see, there are not 100 testcases. Why is that? How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you installed radamsa from https://gitlab.com/akihe/radamsa ? It works correctly for me.

Comment: @sinkmanu yes, I followed [those instructions](https://gitlab.com/akihe/radamsa#nutshell). I tried it on two different VMs, both with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Have you tried on the same OS?

Comment: No. I did it in Debian 10. Your problem is so weird. It looks like the problem is because your SHELL or something is cutting the output.

Comment: @sinkmanu I don't think is a shell problem. I've also tried to generate files starting from a source file, but it does not generate the right number of mutations neither.